# Matrix inversion and transpose

Tags: matrices

$((V^{-1}x)/A)^T$

Which rules would I use to take the transpose of this matrix? I know about $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$, but how do I account for the division in this case?

Comment: How exactly do you divide matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division written this way is bad for matrices. It should be multiply by the inverse, and since multiply is not commutative for matrices, it can not be written as a fraction. Once it is rewritten as multiplication by the inverse, the transpose rule is easy.

Generally speaking this is false:
$$AB^{-1} = B^{-1}A$$

Which is why it does not make sense to write $$\frac{A}{B}$$